# Regarding freedom of choice

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body

If all Human beings are 'super complicated' neuro-chemical biological machines (with all possible 'brain' activities  governed by the laws of physics and chemistry) how can any 'brain' activities even appear to involve a set of behaviors where one behavior is chosen to be acted on and the other is not?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "appear"? There's an importan ambiguity there. Do you mean, "just looking at people's choices, how can they be free if everything is biologically determined?" OR do you mean "in light of everything being biologically determined, how can anyone believe there are free choices?"

Comment: Both meanings you mention involve interesting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that one behavior is chosen while another is not, by looking at brain activity, you can do something like this: find a set of neurons A that start becoming active before behavior 1 is executed; you find a set of neurons B that start becoming active before behavior 2 is executed; and you find when presenting a choice between behavior 1 and 2 that both sets become active but then resolve with strong activation of one (the one which is chosen).

This sort of thing (anticipatory neuronal activity that is enhanced when an action is selected or suppressed if it is not) is observed fairly often.  I don't know whether the *exact* formulation I gave above has been observed, but there is certainly no reason to think it is impossible, and even the possibility is enough to answer the question.

(Anticipatory neural activity is philosophically and experimentally vexing in its own right, see e.g. [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24723870).)

Comment: Is this like Buridan's donkey (forgive spelling if incorrect)?  Where 'competing' sets of neural activity representing two distinct choices ( two 'identical' looking bales of hay one to its left ,one to its right ) are being processed ,when one neural activity set 'wins' out 'telling' the donkey to act on what this represents , that is to eat the left bale, say. Are Human Beings just computing machine's that 'map' discrete 'packages' of neuronal activity to distinct behavior patterns?

Comment: @user128932 - You've got the idea with Buridan's ass.  But neuroscience is incredibly far from being complete.  Saying what human beings "are" (aside from implemented in matter) is woefully premature.  But we can say that neural correlates of the appearance of alternatives and refinement to an individual choice are observed.

Comment: What if a Human being could 'come up with' a seemingly continuous 'stream' of possible choices for alternative 'sets' of neuronal activity and could pick any particular 'set' to 'act on' ,or not as she or he can always interrupt their present choices. Also the whole 'cognitive sea' of choices is being constantly changed by ones own neural activity and what one is aware of. This could account for events of unpredictable neural activity regardless of determinism..

Comment: @user128932 - I do not know of any data that rules out the possibility which you stated.  Something of that sort seems plausible but it's not been robustly verified.

Comment: Is It theoretically possible? Is it possible to have freedom of choice in a deterministic Universe? By the way; we are all supposed to have freedom of expression in a Democracy but can that freedom exist in a deterministic Universe?

Comment: @user128932 - You can have freedom of choice inasmuch as you are the part of the universe that is doing the choosing.  See e.g. Daniel Dennett ("Freedom Evolves" or some other work) for more elaboration of that idea.

Comment: Can part of a Universe be 'doing the choosing'? If this is a deterministic phenomenon then there is 'freedom of choice' a midst a 'mechanical' Universe; is this possible?

Comment: @user128932 - Some people argue that this freedom of choice is as free as anything can be: the part of the universe which is you is selecting from various options.  See e.g. Dennett for more explanation.

Comment: This implies I'm part of the 'machinery' of the universe that is selecting from various options. Can a machine choose something without some sort of 'choosing' algorithm 'written' previously (a pre-programmed algorithm) or with an 'algorithm' that just spontaneously 'formed' somehow? (Why should Dennett who does not seem to believe in the 'mind's' existence be such an authority on the 'mind'?)

Comment: In 'Consciousness Explained' Dennett argued against the existence of consciousness ( I think) and even 'qualia'. Are we just neuro-chemical automatons or neuronal-event puppets? Is Dennett biased against all types of duellism ? (forgive spelling)

Comment: If a human being is some kind of neuronal activity puppet then how does the puppet 'do' any procedure or 'behavioral algorithm'? The puppet (by definition ;being a puppet) can't initiate such action 'itself'; it would just 'follow' a pre-programmed behavioral algorithm that already exists and is 'active' or a program that somehow just 'formed' (with no relevant pre-progamming ). Yet why does it look like 'we' puppets are initiating our own actions to 'do' one or more of these behavioral 'algorithms'? Our 'initiating efforts' might not come from previous behavioral activity..

Comment: @user128932 - I do not have time to write a thesis here!  Dennett argues against the classic ideas of consciousness and qualia, but not against the experiences that we have that motivated them.  Churchland (actually, both Churchlands) ends up at the same point as Dennett, more or less, except by saying that this is what we really (should have) meant by consciousness/qualia all along, IIRC.  Anyway, refusing to put boundaries between you and the rest of the universe causes the same consternation in a non-materialistic view: do _you_ decide or does _God / reality / etc._?

Comment: @user128932 - In case that is not clear enough: suppose we are dualists and posit some disembodied consciousness.  But how is that consciousness _yours_? Why do we say that _you_ choose to do something rather than _this is an influence on some matter caused by the workings of the dual-reality_? If you can draw a boundary around _your_ consciousness as a dualist and claim it for your own, you can equally well draw a boundary around your consciousness implemented materially. It's just an implementation detail.

Comment: If an A.I. system has some kind of information  'management system' (like an operating system in a computer) only it is 'self-controlling' this could be an analogy of the 'mind' as a self-controlling 'idea management system'. Both being self-controlling systems that are self-sustaining. The mind being what is called a 'consciousness'( I think) is a real thing, it is not immaterial or ghostly. . It is not a disembodied consciousness. The mind is a real self-sustaining emergent system embedded in the brain's physical architecture. Of course these are  very controversial ideas in Philosophy.

Comment: Can a sequence of four-dimensional invariant quality-events within the mind-brain be considered a real part of the consciousness and not just intangible. Like an invariant emotional reaction that is part of some person's personality profile; this set of invariant emotional reactions is like a set of programs within the 'personality' that is unchanging in certain ways. So consciousness does not have to be disembodied or intangible but like a real system of self-sustaining programs with invariant qualities.

Comment: If an A.I. system has something like a C.P.U. and it also accurately mimics a Human Mind does this imply the Human Mind has something that functions like a 'central processing unit' or at least a 'central processing system'.

Comment: @user128932 - No, that's an implementation detail.  We know because Turing machines can in principle mimic a CPU or a human mind, and aren't much like either in implementation (just in theoretical capability).

Comment: Can a system of interacting Turing machines solve the halting problem? Are there 'undecidable' problems a computer system can never solve yet a human being can approximate such a problem without having a 'system crash'.

Comment: @user128932 - You mean by letting some Turing machines interrupt the others?  No, though you could potentially use that to guarantee a bounded computation if you prefer that to non-termination.  And humans _do_ crash occasionally: epilepsy.  (They also bound their computations.)

Comment: Is it true the Halting problem can not be solved with a general algorithmic approach? If so an A.I system that works according to 'strictly defined' logic and 'symbols' in it's computational 'algebra' would be hard pressed to 'organize' and synchronize the management of all its interacting programs if it couldn't immediately tell when certain programs will halt. So the Halting problem has a direct bearing on how a self-programming A.I. system can organize itself.

Comment: @user128932 - Indeed.  And it has direct bearing on how the brain might work (not that neuroscientists were really counting on it being able to solve the Halting problem).